# How to receive file data shared from broswer into ReactNative Mobile Application?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

**TLDR;**

I have a react-native mobile application which needs to receive a file shared by ther other application.

**Details:**

I am trying to receive this file inside my own application. And since I am new to React/React-native/Expo/Android development I am not sure how it's coded in react native.

0. connect the mobile device to phone and allow development and tethering. or have emulator ready

**Mobile App:**

run following commands in the terminal:

```
git clone https://github.com/dimaportenko/react-native-receive-share-file-tutorial
run yarn install
run yarn android
```

**Browser:**

4. In broswer of the mobile phone navigate to https://w3c.github.io/web-share/demos/share-files.html
5. Fill Data.
6. Attach a file.
7. click 'Share'
8. Select the 'rnrecievesharetutorial'
9. This should show something like following

   Received Files Array [
   Object {
   "contentUri": null,
   "extension": null,
   "fileName": null,
   "filePath": null,
   "subject": "Credential Offer",
   "text": "Choose a wallet to process this offer.",
   "weblink": null,
   },
   ]

**Question:**

Can you please share some code which allows me to get the file data ?

The website has indeed shared the file data. As a proof: if you select the email/gmail application on your phone it should add the file as an attachement.

Answer (score 0):

You can download data using RNFS

```
import * as RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

let offlinePackageResponse = await RNFS.config({
   fileCache: true,
   timeout: 9999999,
   background: true, // iOS only
}).fetch(method, path, header)
.progress(callback);
    
console.log(`file save at ${offlinePackageResponse.path()}`);
```

you can access the file as

```
await RNFS.readFile(offlinePackageResponse.path(), 'base64')
```

Comment: Appologies for delay to test. Resources weren't available. Thank you for answering. I am getting errors. TS2339: Property 'config' does not exist on type 'typeof import("node_modules/react-native-fs/index")'.

I am not sure if I know what the 'path' should be. In my case I should receive the file in the intent. I am not sure if this is the right lib for that. Can you please share code that I can add to 'react-native-receive-share-file-tutorial' to make it work. 

Ps. I noticed there were more steps mentioned https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs. I followed these as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was not receiving the Location of the local file. I used another lib: https://github.com/meedan/react-native-share-menu. I receive the Location of the file. And then we can use file read/write libs to get the content.

```
RNFS.readFile(data.data)
  .then((fileString: string) => {
    console.log(`file contents : ${fileString}`);
    
  });
```